# How to Display RSS via SyndicationFeed in View

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, asp.net-mvc, rss

I am brand new to ASP.NET and something of great interest to me is pulling and displaying RSS feed from sites ( [example](http://www.wadewegner.com/2011/11/aggregating-rss-feeds-in-c-and-asp-net-mvc-3/) ). I've found several great tutorials but none have demonstrated how to style the feed in a View?

I noticed that when running my ASP.NET MVC project I can see the feed in Internet Explorer but it is just unformatted XML in Chrome. How can I implement a simple style to render this appropriately?

FYI I'm pulling yahoo finance headlines and so here is some [background](https://developer.yahoo.com/finance/company.html#response) for reference.

HomeController.cs

```
public RssActionResult Index()
    {
        SyndicationFeed mainFeed = new SyndicationFeed();

        foreach (var feed in GetRssFeeds())
        {
            Uri feedUri = new Uri(feed);
            SyndicationFeed syndicationFeed;
            using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(feedUri.AbsoluteUri))
            {
                syndicationFeed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);
            }

            syndicationFeed.Id = feed;
            SyndicationFeed tempFeed = new SyndicationFeed(
                mainFeed.Items.Union(syndicationFeed.Items).OrderByDescending(u => u.PublishDate));

            mainFeed = tempFeed;
        }

        return new RssActionResult() { Feed = mainFeed }; 
    }

public class RssActionResult : ActionResult
    {
        public SyndicationFeed Feed { get; set; }

        public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
        {

            context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/rss+xml";
            Rss20FeedFormatter rssFormatter = new Rss20FeedFormatter(Feed);

            using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(context.HttpContext.Response.Output))
            {
                rssFormatter.WriteTo(writer);
            }
        }
    }

    private static List<string> GetRssFeeds()
    {
        List<string> feeds = new List<string>();

        feeds.Add("http://finance.yahoo.com/rss/headline?s=msft,goog,aapl");
        //feeds.Add("http://www.nickharris.net/feed/");  //from example site
        //feeds.Add("http://feeds.feedburner.com/ntotten");  //from example site

        return feeds;
    }
```

Comment: What's your problem? Do you get any error?!

Comment: No error. The problem is I need to style the results so they are formatted the exact same regardless of the browser. For instance, Internet Explorer already acts as an RSS reader, but in chrome I see raw XML. How can I style the results in ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: Hi @Matthew, did you ever manage to get a solution to resolve this? I am having the same issue in google chrome where the XML is displayed rather than a nicely styled feed in other browsers such as Firefox